How to automatically stack three parts of content on small screen?
What I want to achieve is this:
Wide screen: (left width:200px) (middle min-width:800px) (right width:200px) but if (middle 800px) doesn't fit the screen, i.e. screen width is less than 1000px, then stack them as on a small screen.
Small screen: all stacked up vertically, i.e. (middle width:100%) (left width:100%) (right width:100%). Notice that (middle) is on top of the stack.
Can we do this with pure CSS (grid and @media perhaps?) or do we need Javascript?
I tried a number of grid CSS including the one on this post but no luck.

I have finally figured it out using CSS only:


.main-div {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-areas: "Middle" "Left" "Right";
}

@media (min-width:1200px) {
  .main-div {
    grid-template-areas: "Left Middle Right";
  }
}

.left-div {
  grid-area: Left;
  width: 200px;
}

.middle-div {
  grid-area: Middle;
}

.right-div {
  grid-area: Right;
  width: 200px;
}



